# Vim. set command line from a function

Tags: vim

I'm trying to write a function that replaces text in all buffers. So I call Ack to search all the matches and next step I want to set into Quickfix command line this code

```
:QuickFixDoAll %s/foo/boo/gc
```

Seems like I can only call 'exec' function which runs this command immediately and there is no ablility to edit it or cancel at all

I also tried "input" function to read user input but got this error at runtime

`not an editor command`

Any ideas?

.vimrc:

```
function! ReplaceInFiles(o, n)                                                                                                       
    exec "Ack '" . a:o . "'"
    exec "QuickFixDoAll %s/" . a:o . "/" . a:n . "/gc"
endfunction

" QuickFixDoAll
function! QuickFixDoAll(command)
    if empty(getqflist())
        return
    endif
    let s:prev_val = ""
    for d in getqflist()
        let s:curr_val = bufname(d.bufnr)
        if (s:curr_val != s:prev_val)
            exec "edit " . s:curr_val
            exec a:command
        endif
        let s:prev_val = s:curr_val
    endfor
    exec "quit"
endfunction
command! -nargs=+ QuickFixDoAll call QuickFixDoAll(<f-args>)
```

Comment: Is that `QuickFixDoAll` command from you (then show the source code behind it)? So you want to edit / remove some quickfix matches, and then replace the remaining ones, right? I don't fully get the actual problem you're struggling with.

Comment: Added the source code... I want to edit not matches but this command ":QuickFixDoAll %s/foo/boo/gc" before execute it. Actually i want to change last argument to execute replacement with or without confirmation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using input()

This queries both values interactively:

```
function! ReplaceInFiles()                                                                                                       
    let l:o = input('search? ')
    let l:n = input('replace? ')
    exec "Ack '" . l:o . "'"
    exec "QuickFixDoAll %s/" . l:o . "/" . l:n . "/gc"
endfunction
nnoremap <Leader>r :call ReplaceInFiles()<CR>
```

#### Incomplete mapping

```
nnoremap <Leader>r :let o = ''<Bar>exec "Ack '" . o . "'"<Bar>exec "QuickFixDoAll %s/" . o . "//gc"<Home><Right><Right><Right><Right><Right><Right><Right><Right><Right>
```

This one puts the cursor on the right spot for the search. As this value is used twice (Ack and QuickFixDoAll), it is assigned to a variable. After that, move to the end of the command and fill in the replacement in between the `//gc`.

#### Custom parsing

The most comfortable option would be a custom command `:AckAndSubstAll/search/replacement/`. For that, you'd need to parse the two parts in the custom command (like `:s` does). You could do that with `matchstr()`, or use `ingo#cmdargs#substitute#Parse()` from my [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433).

Comment: Thank you, now with "input" function anything works great. Anyway, i didn't use all the features you provided but added "input('additional params? (q=quit) ')" right after ack invoke

Comment: Great! Yes, there are many possible variations. If that solves your problem, please accept the answer by clicking on the outlined arrow next to it.

Answer (score 0):

First use [vim-qargs](https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-qargs) to copy all files from the quickfix window into Vim's arglist by calling `:Qargs`.

Then run your replace on all arguments in the arglist by doing `:argdo %s/search/replace/gc`

Comment: There is a `cdo` command built into vim 7.4.858. Which runs a command for every line in the quick fix list.